# Jboss server related issue

Tags: server, jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x, jboss5.x

Packages waiting for a deployer:
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@148f67e2 { url=file:D:/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp6ems.ear-contents/ems.sar-contents/log4j-api-2.17.1.jar }
deployer: null
status: Starting
state: START_SUBDEPLOYMENTS
watch: file:/D:/server/default/tmp/deploy/tmp6ems.ear-contents/ems.sar-contents/log4j-api-2.17.1.jar
lastDeployed: 1648198884682
lastModified: 1648198880962

Error deploying war in JBoss

Comment: What version of WildFly, JBoss AS or JBoss EAP are you using? You've tagged 3 different versions.

Comment: Jboss Eap we are using

Comment: Which version of JBoss EAP?